# Can I trim start and end whitespace from PHP's shell_exec() output?

Tags: php, trim, shell-exec

I'm running `shell_exec` (`git log` in this example) and my response has a lot of whitespace at the start and end of the string.

```
                    7baca58 test 3
847ad88 test 3
bcd7340 Nother test
21a5f17 Testing git releases
8faa1c0 Add previously ignored files in attempt to push to server with git
```

I have tried `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);` but this also removes the line breaks as well. Normal `trim` also doesn't seem to help.

How can I just remove the leading and trailing spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces and tabs, should keep line breaks, try it:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[ \t]+/", " ", $string);
```

For only spaces remove the \t

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);` will replace all whitespaces.
To trim whitespaces from begining and end of string, try [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).
If you need to trim **all lines** from your string, try

```
$s = '';
foreach(explode("\n", $lines) as $line) {
    $s. = trim($line);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to explode the string. It just returns an array with one item.

Comment: Examine your input correctly - what are the EOL chars, etc. Because this would normally work. You can try to replace '\n' with '\r'.